# How to remove an overlay from a different class

Tags: flutter, dart

I inserted an overlay in one class and tried to remove it from another class buy using timeout.

Here is the class holding the overlay

```
    class Notify extends StatelessWidget{
    

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text('hey');
  }
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;

  void _insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Material(
          color: const Color(0xFF0E3311).withOpacity(0.2),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: ()=>_overlayEntry?.remove(),
            child:Icon(Icons.home, size: 100,),
          )
        ),
      );
    });
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }
  
  

  void show(BuildContext context){
    _insertOverlay(context); 
  }

  void dismiss(){
    _overlayEntry?.remove();
  }
}
```

I inserted the overlay and set the timeout by taping on the icon on another class. Here is  the class. I want to remove it after setting time set in this same class. Please see the class below

```
    class Fd extends StatelessWidget{

  late  Timer rtime;
  int _start=4;
  int _dstart=4;

  Timer timeItOut() {

      const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
      rtime = new Timer.periodic(
        oneSec,
            (Timer timer)
            {
        
        
            if (_start == 1) {
              _start = _dstart;
              rtime.cancel();
              Notify().dismiss();
            } else {
              _start = _start - 1;
              print('still counting down $_start');
            }

            }
      );
      return rtime;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Feeding the nation'),),
      body: Container(
        child:IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.food_bank),onPressed: (){timeItOut(); Notify().show(context);},)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The remove method worked very well withing the class I inserted the overlay by taping on the built overlay but didn't worked when I tried implementing it outside the class holding the overlay

Comment: Why did you use MediaQuery, instead Positioned.fill, which makes it as big as it can go.

Comment: Thank you @RandalSchwartz, I didn't know I can use that before now, instead of use those extra parameters

Comment: Can I know why you are using this? Are you want to show for loading purpose?

Comment: Yes I want to use it for loading purpose and I also want to re-use it for all other classes I will have in future that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours of searching, I found no solution, so I had to restructure my my code to something that look like what I needed and it worked perfectly for me.

I wanted to avoid too many texts in every class I want to implement the overlay by have to create the overlay in a separate class and implementing it in every class that it's needed.

For those who may need it, please see my solution below

Overlay class here...

```
class Notify extends StatelessWidget{
    

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text('hey');
  }

  OverlayEntry _insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Material(
          color: const Color(0xFF0E3311).withOpacity(0.2),
          child: GestureDetector(
            //onTap: ()=>_overlayEntry?.remove(),
            child:Icon(Icons.home, size: 100,),
          )
        ),
      );
    });
    //Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }
  
  

  void show(BuildContext context, OverlayEntry _overlayentry){
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayentry); 
  }

  void dismiss(OverlayEntry _overlayEntry){
    _overlayEntry.remove();
  }
}
```

called and implemented in the class below...

```
class Fd extends StatelessWidget{

      late  Timer rtime;
      int _start=4;
      int _dstart=4;

      OverlayEntry? _overlayentry;

      Timer timeItOut() {

          const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
          rtime = new Timer.periodic(
            oneSec,
                (Timer timer)
                {
            
            
                if (_start == 1) {
                  _start = _dstart;
                  rtime.cancel();
                  Notify().dismiss(_overlayentry!);
                } else {
                  _start = _start - 1;
                  print('still counting down $_start');
                }

                }
          );
          return rtime;
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        _overlayentry = Notify()._insertOverlay(context);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Feeding the nation'),),
          body: Container(
            child:IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.food_bank),onPressed: (){timeItOut(); Notify().show(context,_overlayentry!);},)
          ),
        );
      }
  }
```

Comment: I'd still appreciate if there's a better way of doing this.